# Why not showing swagger response data in all format Content type

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

net web api swagger respnse is not showing in all format for some of methods

I want to display in this format.
**application/json,
test/json,
application/xml and 
text/xml**

but it's showing only
**application/json and 
test/json** in some of apis.
how can i fix this issue?

If api returning List and IEnumerable so It's working fine.
but if working only some class object then it's not showing all format.

Comment: The following blog article describes how to create an attribute `SwaggerProducesAttribute` to customize Swashbuckle and achieve what you describe: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/04/swashbuckle-pro-tips-for-aspnet-web-api-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your are having this issue ONLY in some apis.
You should compare your api projects specifically the `WebApiConfig` class that's where we can remove and add formats like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new BrowserJsonFormatter());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

You can see my full example here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs#L33

Comment: Actually I am getting  thease format (application/json, test/json, application/xml and text/xml) in case of return type list and IEnumerable. but i am getting only json format in case of return type class. Your code is already exists it's also showing in case of list and IEnumreable.

Comment: but it's added in drop down but not changing the value of json to xml or any other format.

Comment: Can you create a minimal project reproducing your issue ?

Comment: i will let you know once i will create minimal project.  thanks